# What is wrong with my pm2 (node.js) deploy?

Tags: node.js, pm2

Trying to deploy my node.js application using pm2, but have the following issue:

```
Cloning into '/var/www/source'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

  failed to clone

Deploy failed
```

My server's key has been added to github deployment keys. And if I don git clone repository on that machine - I can clone with no issues (repo is private). Thoughts?

What tools do you guys you for deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently came up removing passphrase from my private key using the following line:

```
openssl rsa -in ~/.ssh/id_rsa -out ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Might b not that elegant, but it just works.